# Can I get the android theme default values on a react native application expo app (CRNA)?

Tags: android, react-native, colors, android-theme, expo

### Context

I'm developing an app which shows some dark text over a light background on the main screen. I want to take the colors from the android theme, changing with each phone. I'm having some differences between 2 approaches, react native init and create react native app (expo).

In the react-native-cli version the  component renders gray text on my redmi note 4, and black text (with a weird white outline) on my moto G. This behavior is what I want, cause react native uses the default text color from android's appcompat theme.

But I tried making another app with create-react-native-app. And the text is always black, because instead of taking the value from the system expo overrides it with black, [here](https://github.com/expo/expo/blob/master/android/app/src/main/res/values/styles.xml) and [here](https://github.com/expo/expo/blob/master/android/app/src/main/res/values/colors.xml) are the relevant files in expo client app's github. Mainly line 25 on styles.xml and line 4 on colors.xml (it's not actually pure black, it's #011A2D)

I want the behavior I had with react-native init. But I also want to run my application using the expo client on the play store, so I can show it to clients for testing using the expo app instead of distributing apks. So I thought I could change the styles on css, but for that I need to know the values of the theme currently running.

### Question

Is there any api available from js that could allow me to reach into native android theme colors, so that I can apply them on css and override expo client app styles?

Comment: Hi, I work on Expo. Expo currently doesn't support falling back to the default theme (the reason for this is that some themes caused React Native text inputs to render inconsistently) but you could add a feature request to https://expo.canny.io/feature-requests.